# Send message to iframe inside of a promise

Tags: javascript

I have this promise? How can I postMessage to an iframe from *then*. Currently i have function with timer that sends info on page load but i want to get more info.

```
const socket = io('/')
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid')
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
  path: '/peerjs',
  host: '/',
  port: '3000'
})
const peers = {}
let myVideoStream;
const myVideo = document.createElement('video')
myVideo.muted = true;

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function brodcastStatus(postMsg) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    parent.postMessage(postMsg, "*");
    console.log(postMsg)
    await sleep(1500)
  }
}

if (KIND === 'server'){
  Promise.resolve(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080,
      aspectRatio: { ideal: 1.7777777778 },
      frameRate: { max: 24, }
    },
    audio: true
  })).then(stream => {
    brodcastStatus("server | camera | mic")
    myVideoStream = stream;

    myPeer.on('call', call => {
      call.answer(stream)
      const video = document.createElement('video')
      call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
      })
    })

    socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
      connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
    })

  }).catch(() => {
    Promise.resolve(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: {
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
        aspectRatio: { ideal: 1.7777777778 },
        frameRate: { max: 24, }
      },
      audio: false
    })).then(stream => {
      brodcastStatus("server | camera | no mic")
      myVideoStream = stream;

      myPeer.on('call', call => {
        call.answer(stream)
        const video = document.createElement('video')
        call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
          addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
        })
      })

      socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
        connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
      })

    }).catch(() => {
      console.log("nocamera or microphone")
    })
  })
}else if (KIND === 'client'){
  Promise.resolve(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: false,
    audio: true
  })).then(stream => {
    brodcastStatus("client | no camera | mic")
    myVideoStream = stream;

    myPeer.on('call', call => {
      call.answer(stream)
      const video = document.createElement('video')
      call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
      })
    })

    socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
      connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
    })

  }).catch(() => {
    console.log("Client")
    newStream = new MediaStream();
    stream = newStream;
    myVideoStream = stream;
    myPeer.on('call', call => {
      call.answer(stream)
      const video = document.createElement('video')
      call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
      })
    })
  
    socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
      connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
    })    

  })

}

socket.on('user-disconnected', userId => {
  if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close()
})


myPeer.on('open', id => {
  socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id)
})


function connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
  const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream)
  const video = document.createElement('video')
  call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
  })
  call.on('close', () => {
    video.remove()
  })

  peers[userId] = call
}


function addVideoStream(video, stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream
  video.setAttribute("style", "object-fit:cover; background: transparent url(/images/New_DACL_Logo.png) no-repeat center center; background-size: auto; overflow: hidden;")
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
  })
  videoGrid.append(video)
}
```

More context

this app send audio/video to user via webrtc. I using this webpage as an iframe in other application (flask) and i want to get some data about current connected user to lock/unlock other options

Comment: Errors please ?

Comment: there is no error i just don't get the message in the parent website

Comment: it sounds like the window reference is `null` then. Check the value of `parent`

Comment: when i window.addEventListener("message", e => { console.log(e) }); i dont get any message but when i move my code outside the promise im getting the messages

Comment: "_when i move my code outside the promise_" - What code are you moving. That should have no bearing. There must be other code that has not been shared here.

Comment: In other words. When I call brodcastStatus outside the promise i get the msg, if i call it inside of then i don't get the msg

Comment: You'll have to deal with the promise being returned from `brodcastStatus` within the other Promise created by `.then()`. This should not have that effect, but it seems that is the issue.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Well, ordinarily, you provide the minimal, reproducible example. I'll be happy to modify that example.

Comment: You missed the point. You need to provide a _*working*_  example that demonstrates your issue - I'll be happy to modify _that_ working example. What you have above is partial and not working.

Comment: I've added rest of the code. This wont run without nodejs backend but you shoudl be able to get the gist